# script to open terminal with multiple tabs and different directories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I find myself opening the same set of terminals every time I startup.

I have 3 tabs in a certain directory, all with python venv's activated, and then one extra tab for ssh'ing if I need to. It takes quite a few keystrokes to do this, and I would like to automate it, but I am drawing a blank on how to do it, and my searches and preliminary attempts have failed.

How can I do this via script?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a set of scripts and call each one per tab, like so:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=BLAH --working-directory=/usr  -e "bash -c 'echo HELLO; bash'"   \
      --tab-with-profile=CRT --working-directory=/bin -e "bash -c 'echo WORLD; bash'"
```

Note the use of `bash` at the end in case you need interacting